# Float related numerical stability issues for parallel reduction

Tags: mpi, openmp, openmpi

I have been looking at some online resources related to float summation and the related accuracy issues. 
E.g.:
https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1044661/cuda-programming-and-performance/how-to-improve-float-array-summation-precision-and-stability-/

https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00949355v4/document

Most of them recommend using some form of manual intervention when handling floating-point summation for any modern hardware. E.g.
(1) to use Kahan’s algorithm for float summation, or (2) Sort and sum closer magnitude numbers together, etc.
Are these kind of nuances handled by MPI_AllReduce or OpenMP reduction kernels?

Comment: You are correct that some possible orders of reduction summation may be unsatisfactory, such as summing without extra precision in order of thread arrival.  Kahan's algorithm is inherently sequential. Simd parallel buys usually a small improvement in accuracy; if you wish extra precision you must write it in. In case your MPI doesn't have a hidden or default option of extra precision, you can test writing it explicitly, or saving individual threaded sums and combining them with explicit extra precision, possibly in tree fashion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speaking only for OpenMP: the standard says nothing about the order in which reduction operations are applied, and, indeed, that can even differ at each execution of the code. (Some OpenMP runtimes, such as the LLVM/Intel one implement a deterministic reduction*, but only guarantee determinism between runs with the same number of threads).

If you want to sort, or perform reduction in other ways, you will need to implement it yourself...

- See https://software.intel.com/en-us/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference-supported-environment-variables and search for KMP_DETERMINISTIC_REDUCTION for details.